# Adapting Cursor in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a simple Cursor in SQL Server that I would like to adapt to use in Teradata.

The goal of the cursor is to collect the names of a series of tables and rename them using cursor logic.

I already change most of the cursor code to use in Teradata, but I'm still having some trouble to finish this.

So far I have:

```
    DECLARE varTableOldName VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE varTableNewName VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE vardbName VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE varIDCod VARCHAR(5);
    DECLARE varRename VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE varCt INT DEFAULT 0; 

DECLARE renameTables CURSOR FOR
    
    SELECT
        DBname
        ,TBname
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DatabaseName AS DBname
            ,TableName AS TBname
            ,LastAccessTimeStamp AS LADate
            ,(CURRENT_DATE - CAST(LastAccessTimeStamp AS DATE)) AS NAccessDate
        FROM
            DBC.TablesV
        WHERE
            1=1
            AND TableKind = 'T'
            AND DatabaseName IN ('PD_BACKUP')
        GROUP BY
            DatabaseName
            ,TableName
            ,LastAccessTimeStamp
            ,LastAlterTimeStamp
    ) tbHig
    WHERE NAccessDate IS NULL OR NAccessDate >= 180
    ORDER BY DBname, TBname

FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN renameTables;

    FETCH NEXT FROM renameTables
    INTO vardbName, varTableOldName;
    
    WHILE (SQLCODE = 0)
    
        DO
        
        SET varTableNewName = vardbName || '_V' || CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR(20)) || '_' || CAST(varCt AS VARCHAR(20));
    
    
        SET varTableOldName = vardbName || '.' || varTableOldName;
    
        SET varRename = 'RENAME TABLE ' || varTableOldName || ' TO ' || varTableNewName;
        
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varRename;
    
        SET varCt = varCt + 1;
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM renameTables INTO vardbName, varTableOldName;

    END WHILE;

CLOSE renameTables;
```

I think the problem is with some syntax details or something.

Can anyone guide me with this please?

Comment: what's the problem? what's your question ? also probably you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Two obvious issues: There is no DEALLOCATE cursor statement in TD SPL. And you need to DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER if you want to be able to check SQLCODE / SQLSTATE in-line. Or consider using a FOR-loop cursor.

Comment: Also, why join to DBC.TableSizeV (which has multiple rows per table)?

Comment: Your code is fine besides a missing space before `IS NULL`. Of course, you need to wrap it in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thank you guys for you help so far. I'm still working on some details, but I appreciate the tips. I already remove the DEALLOCATE statement, the join and now and now I'm researching the proper way to wrap everything in a stored procedure.

Comment: That's simple (as long as you got CREATE PROCEDURE rights):`replace procedure myproc() begin <existing code here> end;`